# Enforce array value by interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I wanted to create interface enforcing certain `Array` value, for example:

```
interface HaveAppleKey {
    kinds: Array<string>; // "Apple" have to be inside
                              // Array<"Apple" and other strings>
}
```

And I want to be sure that if some class implements my interface I can be sure that `"Apple"` key will be inside this array in class implementation.

My question is simple - Is is possible to achieve it using typescript Interface?

---

*Some background*

I wanted to be sure that every implemented class has some "property" in runtime because Interface exist only in typescript. I know it is strange way to do this and also I know type gurads exists but I wanted to make my life easier for current implementation so instead of checking some `class.property` I just wanted to check value in array instead of making function for every Interface.

Is there other more "automated" way to check that class implements Iterface avoiding creating typeguards for every Interface?

Comment: You can make the array of type your-custom-enum, so it will have predefined options.

Comment: The problem is that this way I have predefined options but I am not sure that class implementing `HaveAppleInterface` have "Apple" but I only know it has one of predefined types, correct?

Comment: Yes, this lets you control only what options are available.